# use segue with kind present modally by code

Tags: ios, swift, navigationcontroller

I have `custom navigation bar` and content a button bar
I need create segue from my bar button to my custom navigation with kind `present modally` but programmatically not from storyboard
this work but segue kind is `push`

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController("", animated: true)
```

what I should do get it with `present modally`

Comment: Screeshot of your storyboard?

Comment: @TonyHan https://s4.postimg.org/kwfoglpfh/Screen_Shot_1437_11_18_at_11_00_37_AM.png

Comment: Accoording to your description,you want wo show a controller in the `present modally` way. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Accoording to your description,you want wo show a controller in the `present modally` way.Add a UIButton or something like UIButton(UIBarButtonItem).

[image]

How about this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "present", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(clickRightItem))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton;
}

func clickRightItem() {
    let controllerToPresent = UIViewController()
    controllerToPresent.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    presentViewController(controllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

Comment: Yes but I want do that programmatically

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple solution with a NavigationController to present modally .

```
yourviewcontroller *myviewc= [[yourviewcontroller alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:myviewc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and for the seconde if you have a navigation controller .

```
let myvc= self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController") as! ViewController
    let navc= UINavigationController(rootViewController: myvc) 
    self.presentViewController(navc, animated:true, completion: nil)
```

You need just to create an IBAction for your Button. this Tutorial can help you to do it [IBAction](http://rshankar.com/different-ways-to-connect-ibaction-to-uibutton/)

Hope it help !

Comment: Where I should write that `AddTaskViewController ...` ?

Comment: its your viewcontroller that you want to show modally !!